# Google App SSO allowing to sign-in directly

Tags: single-sign-on, google-apps

I created an account in Google App. My normal (not admin) mail id is **test@example.com**. If I try to log-in to **gmail.com** with my **test@exampl.com** credential, I am getting error as given below.
[image]

It provides the link to my website to do SSO.

But if I am using **google.com/a/example.com** instead of **gmail.com**, I can log-in.
Then why Google says "It doesn't know your password".

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior for an SSO enabled domain. The user needs to authenticate via SSO.

Jay

Comment: That is the Control Panel login URL and is not generally meant for end users.

Comment: They mean it or not is not an issue. But I can login.